# As soon as VisaulVm.exe launches Intellij becomes unresponsive

Tags: java, intellij-idea, visualvm, intellij-12

I am using IntelliJ and the moment that I open VisiualVm.exe IntelliJ just becomes unresponsive. I can use VisualVm correctly and even after I close it IntelliJ just hangs. I have to kill it from the TaskManager.

I tried google’ing for this but cannot seem to find any post related to this and don’t really have an idea where to start debugging this. Any Ideas?

I am using

- JDK 1.7.0_51 (64Bit)
- Windows 7 64Bit
- IntelliJ 12
- VisiualVm 1.3.5

Comment: Why don't you ask this question on IntelliJ Idea support forum?

Comment: I have submitted a request as well... The email that I receveid from them had "We also recommend checking http://stackoverflow.com/ for similar questions (our support team answers there as well)."